How can I have dynamic file upload locations based on e.g. media category?
For my media type "video" I can define the upload file location such as "sites/default/files/video/" at /admin/structure/media/manage/video/fields/media.video.field_media_video_file - but is it possible for the user to create a subfolder when uploading so that videos can be grouped by subject such as "sites/default/files/video/football" "sites/default/files/video/hockey" etc ?
[]
tokens =

media type file path =


Not out of the box, with core methods. But media entities are fieldable, which means you could add an additional taxonomy field to your video entity with your desired categories. (Which would have additional goodies on the long run, like making filterable views of all football videos...)

One way to do this is with the Filefield Paths module.  This module does not allow users to create subdirectories directly.  Instead, you can create subdirectories based on tokens.  This can be any token in Drupal, such as the date (year/month/day), or a taxonomy term.  Taxonomy terms can work really well because they have parent->child relationships, so you could configure the file path to be grandparent/parent/child (or as deep as you want) with tokens.
EDIT: Before installing Filefield Paths, try using the tokens provided by core; core supports tokens in paths.  But, it may not make all tokens available, so you may need to install Filefield Paths to get the tokens you need.

Does that module still do anything? Core file fields have supported tokens for a while now

Oh ok it also does file names. Probably not necessary for what the OP needs though, core functionality should work fine just for the folder

Thanks for replies - I have added two scsreenshots to my question - my media type has a field called tax_term so any ideas please why taxonomy term is not in the availablo tokens for the file path?

@Juc1 Did you install Filefield Paths module?  Try entering the token even if it doesn't show up in the list, something like [media:field_tax_term:entity:name].

@PatrickKenny I thought Clive said that core could use tokens in file path so I was trying it with core but my token [media:field_tax_term:entity] was rejected as invalid - see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3067884 - so maybe core can do some tokens in the file path but not taxonomy tokens so I enabled Filefield Paths module so now the same token is accepted and the file path is working, thank you.
